# Version Mismatches with Kendo-Angular-*

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I'm trying to get Kendo UI with integrated with my Angular (4) project and I'm running into peer dependency errors. I need to use @progress/kendo-angular-grid and @progress/kendo-angular-charts and the but the latest of both are requiring different versions of @progress/kendo-drawing. @progress/kendo-angular-grid@0.26.0 wants 0.14.0 of @progress/kendo-drawing and @progress/kendo-angular-charts@0.22.0 wants 0.15.0 of @progress/kendo-drawing. Anyone know what the correct version numbers should be so that everything installs correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Use the latest version of kendo-drawing (0.15). Both the grid and charts are compatible with it, but the grid dependency is outdated (which will be fixed soon). The grid requires a more recent version due to the PDF export feature.